# Why generic + interface + shadowing methods cannot work together?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, shadow

In C#, mixing generic, interfaces and shadow methods (new keyword in C#) does not seems to work as exepected (in my opinion).
Explicit methods marked as new (shadow) behave as overriding methods !

Here is an use case :

Create a C# winforms project, remove generated Form1.cs
and replace Program.cs with this code :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GenericWithShadowedMethImplInterface
{

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new ChildForm());
        }
    }

    public interface IStepByStep_UI_Initialization
    {
        void FillControls();
        void DefineBindings();
        // etc...
    }

    public class BaseForm : Form, IStepByStep_UI_Initialization
    {
        public StringBuilder Log = new StringBuilder();

        public BaseForm()
        {
            this.InstallSmartLoading();
            Shown += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(Log.ToString());
        }

        public void FillControls()
        {
            Log.AppendLine("BaseObject.FillControls");
        }

        public void DefineBindings()
        {
            Log.AppendLine("BaseObject.DefineBinding");
        }
    }

    public class ChildForm : BaseForm, IStepByStep_UI_Initialization
    {
        public ChildForm()
        {
            this.InstallSmartLoading();
        }
        // Shadowing is really what i want
        public new void FillControls()
        {
            Log.AppendLine("ChildObject.FillControls");
        }

        // Shadowing is really what i want
        public new void DefineBindings()
        {
            Log.AppendLine("ChildObject.DefineBinding");
        }
    }

    public static class StepByStepInitializer
    {
        public static void InstallSmartLoading<TForm>(this TForm form)
            where TForm : Form, IStepByStep_UI_Initialization
        {
            // i Use lambda to keep knowing what form type really is (BaseForm or ChildForm)
            form.Load += (_, __) =>
            {
                // I would expect the these two lines of code here...
                // Why these calls are treated as polymorphic calls ?
                form.FillControls(); // always call ChildForm.FillControls even if typeof(TForm) == typeof(BaseForm)
                form.DefineBindings();

                // ... behaves likes this (not generic) code :
                //if (typeof(TForm) == typeof(BaseForm))
                //{
                //    (form as BaseForm).FillControls();
                //    (form as BaseForm).DefineBindings();
                //}
                //else if (typeof(TForm) == typeof(ChildForm))
                //{
                //    (form as ChildForm).FillControls();
                //    (form as ChildForm).DefineBindings();
                //}
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Run it...

You should see :

```
    ChildObject.FillControls
    ChildObject.DefineBindings
    ChildObject.FillControls
    ChildObject.DefineBindings
```

Now if you comment the two lines of code in InstallSmartLoading and uncomment the other lines of code, then run the project again you should see  :

```
    BaseObject.FillControls
    BaseObject.DefineBindings
    ChildObject.FillControls
    ChildObject.DefineBindings
```

So my question is simple : Why the two lines of code you have commented do not behave like the code you have uncommented ? I need my base BaseForm to be fully initialized before initialising ChildForm. Is this a limitation of generics ? :(((
Is there a workaround

- TForm means the real Form type though...
- Methods are not marked as virtual / override, I explicitely use new keyword
- Compiler should not display a warning about that ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you from a C++ background by any chance? In C++, whilst a base class constructor is running, the "type" of the object is that base class type. Whereas in C#, objects don't change their type during construction/destruction - they're always of their final type.

Comment: _"I need my base BaseForm to be fully initialized before initialising ChildForm. Is this a limitation of generics ? :((( Is there a workaround"_  Why can't you just call `base.FillControls();` in `ChildForm.FillControls()`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes my mind is built on C++. Nevertheless i use C# since 6-7 years now and i do like it. This is the first time i find a code not really intuitive.

Comment: @Greg Because in our project we want to define a standard way to initialize forms. Currently we have 7-8 steps : DefineBindings, FillControls, CustomizeUI, WireEvents, etc... So when I (or any developper) want to do a new form the rule is simple : implement this interface and call Install in Constructor. For example the initializer handles the fact that Visual studio swallow exception in Form Load events.... Moreover if someone else wants to debug or improve the form he will now where to look at even if he never developped this form.

Comment: _So when I (or any developper) want to do a new form the rule is simple : implement this interface and call Install in Constructor._ The implementation you posted to solve this problem seems incredibly convoluted, maybe I'm missing something.  If that's the entire purpose of it, I would recommend making your BaseForm abstract (this isn't strictly necessary) and call the appropriate methods, in order, in some private method on the BaseForm. You can look at WPF window lifecycle as an example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403418/Lifetime-events-of-a-WPF-application

Comment: @Greg To answer your question: If a developper 1 makes BaseForm and a developper 2 makes ChildForm, we want they dont have to communicate about anything. I mean we want the way they load their form to be completely independant. Before ChildForm begins to initialize itself we want BaseForm to be completely initialized. Why? Because ChildForm may need to read values in BaseForm's controls to initialize ChildForm UI.
When developper 1 handles control's events in BaseForm, he should not have to think: "Hey what if developper 2 raises this event before i am done with loading data in my controls ?"

Comment: Ho sorry ! I wanted to change my message and get interrupted by someone. So i remove and repaste my corrected message...

Comment: What if ChildForm has a combobox and want to fill it in FillControls ... according to a value selected in another combobox managed by BaseForm ?
The value in a BaseForm combobox would not be databound yet if i use polymorphism. using explicit implement in each Form is to run all method of BaseForm **then** all methods in ChildForm

This is exactly like saying you want to execute a piece of ChildForm Constructor while BaseForm Constructor is not completely done. Instead of code in constructor i am talking about UI Initialization in different events (Load Shown etc)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Trezamere/39ae8ebcaf3df57febd8 This will output _I am a foobar! I am a foo!_ I think you are over-complicating it.  The same pattern can be applied anywhere in the `BaseForm`, including event handlers if you need finer control during UI initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have the constraint

```
where TForm : IStepByStep_UI_Initialization
```

(the other part of the constraint is not relevant right now), then you have a variable (actually parameter)

```
TForm form
```

on which you do:

```
form.FillControls(); // always call ChildForm.FillControls even if typeof(TForm) == typeof(BaseForm)
```

(your commment from the question).

The reason why it compiles is because you have this interface constraint.

Note that `ChildForm` ***re-implements*** the interface `IStepByStep_UI_Initialization` which was already implemented by the `BaseForm`.

So your call is really equivalent to

```
((IStepByStep_UI_Initialization)form).FillControls();
```

and **it becomes irrelevant what `TForm` is**. All that matters is how the instance implements the interface.

Try the following:

- stop re-implementing the interface, so only implement it at `BaseForm`, **or**
- change interface constraint to base class constraint `where TForm : BaseForm`

to enhance your understanding.

---

Here is a related example with no generics, no delegates and events, no Win Forms:

```
interface ICanTalk
{
  void Talk();
}

class Animal : ICanTalk
{
  public void Talk()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("I am animal");
  }
}
class Dog : Animal, ICanTalk // note: re-implements
{
  public new void Talk() // note: method hiding "new" is always evil
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Wroof!");
  }
}

static class Test
{
  internal static void Run()
  {
    object x = new Dog();

    ((Animal)x).Talk();   // I am animal
    ((Dog)x).Talk();      // Wroof!
    ((ICanTalk)x).Talk(); // Wroof!
  }
}
```

Please note that changing `object x = ...` above into `Animal x` or `Dog x` is not relevant, meaning it will not change what method is called.

Comment: Actually, in your code, compiler considers the object as an Animal / Dog. So when it calls the method it knows only about Animal.Talk or else Dog.Talk (because methods are not virtual).
In my case, with generic I say to compiler : form is an object **of type TForm** that implements IStepByStep.... IStepByStep... is just here to constraints TForm, not replacing it. So the generic method should use TForm, not the interface. I think that because i am coming from C++.
I think it's weird though, because there is no difference about what code means if i use generic method or interface.

Comment: The weird thing, in my opinion, is the fact that 
`void Foo<TBar>(TBar bar) where TBar : IBaz) {... }`
is equivalent to
`void Foo(IBaz bar) {... }`

Comment: @MickaëlL The method to bind to is selected at compile-time (this is not `dynamic` typing) *before* it is known what `TForm` is. Two methods with the same name and signature are not "related", no matter if you include the `new` or modifier or not. Actually hiding methods like that is discouraged and leads to confusion. You are right C# generics are not like C++ templates.